# How to run this threads example?

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I'm trying the code from Tanenbaum's 3e "Modern Operating Systems" and I get compiler errors and warnings:

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 cc thread.c 
thread.c: In function ‘main’:
thread.c:19:63: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
thread.c:25:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:544:13: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
/tmp/ccqxmMgE.o: In function `main':
thread.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the code I'm trying

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS   10

void *print_hello_world(void *tid)
{
  //printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d0", tid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
  int status, i;

  for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
  //printf("Main here creating thread %d0", i);
  status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_hello_world, (void *)i);

  if (status != 0) {
    //printf("Oops. pthread_create returned error code %d0", status);
    exit(-1);
  }
}
exit(NULL);
}
```

Can you help me improve the state of the code so that it will run? There appears to be some errata since the exact code from the book doesn't compile. Thanks

Comment: This "warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" seems to be because you are using exit(NULL) instead of exit(-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please link to pthread library, by specifying -lpthread option to your linker.

Also, you should be using [pthread_join](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/) to wait for all the created threads to complete.

Comment: pthread_exit(NULL) also a possible solution. you can add before exit(NULL).

Comment: That's very interesting and also solved the `printf` call. Is the `printf` also defined from pthread library?

Answer (score 1):

```
$gcc thread.c -lpthread
```

This is to link the pthread shared library.

Comment: Excellent! It seems to work as I get this output from a.out now: `Main here creating thread 00Main here creating thread 10Hello World. Greetings from thread 00Main here creating thread 20Hello World. Greetings from thread 10Main here creating thread 30Main here creating thread 40Main here creating thread 50Main here creating thread 60Hello World. Greetings from thread 50Hello World. Greetings from thread 40Hello World. Greetings from thread 30Hello World. Greetings from thread 20Main here creating thread 70Hello World. Greetings from thread 60Main here creating thread 80Hello World...`

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to link to libpthread to get rid of the linker error:

```
gcc ..... -lpthread
```

(note that the -lpthread option must be the last one)!

2) `exit(NULL);` is wrong; NULL is for pointer types whereas exit wants an int to be supplied; use simply

```
exit(0);
```

instead.

The other warnings are just system-dependent pointer and integer size warnings; they can safely be ignored in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Pl. do not use the exit statement in your main function in this case, since the main may get exited and your threads also will terminate and you may not get  the outputs of the print statement in the thread function.

Pl. use pthread_exit instead of exit in main so that even your main thread terminates the other threads can continue.